# angularJS access properties of promised object in succes function

Tags: angularjs, http, object, promise, angular-promise

I have a problem where i really can't get my head around. I'm using a basic angular http.get which returns a promise:

```
getTask: function(id) {
    var promise = $http.get('http://localhost:9000/get/tasks/'+id).success(function(data) {
            return data;
        });
        return promise;
    }
TasksService.getTask($stateParams.id).then(function(success){
    $scope.task = success.data;
});
```

The task has propperties which i want to access, but it somehow always returns undefined. if i for example do:

```
TasksService.getTask($stateParams.id).then(function(success){
    $scope.task = success.data;
    console.log($scope.task.deadline);
});
```

it's undefined. Do you have any idea how i can access the properties and how can then share it with the rest of my controller?

Comment: show the code for `getTask`

Comment: I can't wrap my head around your question... are you asking why your returned data is undefined?

Comment: updated the question with my get task. My question is why my, for example, $scope.task.deadline is undefined. Since it's a property of the object

Comment: just found it: it should be. $scope.task.task[0].deadline

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the confusion of `.success` vs. `.then` strikes again. This subtle (and, in my opinion, completely unnecessary) difference that Angular introduced have spawn a lot of issues.

The issue here is that `.success` returns the original promise and, in that respect, disregards the `data` that you return. In other words, it "branches off" and allows to implement a handler that does not affect the rest of the chain.

To fix, use `.then`:

```
return $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
  return response.data;
});
```

**Addendum:**

To better understand, `.success` conceptually behaves as follows:

```
promise.success = function(fn) {
   promise.then(function(response) {
     fn(response.data, response.status, response.headers, config);
   });

   // the original promise is returned, not the .then promise
   return promise;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would advise you to inspect variables with [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method like this:

```
 var obj = {};
 obj['key_1'] = 1;
 obj['key_2'] = 2;
 alert(Object.keys(obj));
```

This method will tell you a lot about variable properties and supported methods.

Comment: Wonder why people are voting down. The user eventually found the solution `$scope.task.task[0].deadline` and indeed with `Object.keys($scope.task)` and further inspection he could finally reach the solution much faster.

Answer (score -1):

Fix it by doing this: `$scope.task.task[0].deadline`

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer to this question!  Code-only answers [are discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274) on Stack Overflow, because a code dump with no context doesn't explain how or why the solution will work, making it impossible for the original poster (or any future readers) to understand the logic behind it.  Please, edit your question and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from your answer.